# Make function only visible to objective-c

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have a method that I only want to be visible to those using Objective-C:

```
@objc static func foo() {}
```

Currently this is visible to both Swift and Objective-C.

I tried adding `@available(*, unavailable)` above the function but that hides it both for Swift and Objective-C developers.

Is this achievable?

Comment: No, if you are defining that function in Swift, you cannot make it invisible to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can do this, by making the function obsolete in swift:

```
@available(swift, obsoleted: 1.0)
```